# Groupby sample pandas with keeping the groups lower than n if applicable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset, on which I want to do sampling after groupby. In general it can be achieved with `df.groupby("some_id").sample(n=100)` . But the problem is that some groups have less than 100 samples (and yes replace=True is a choice but what if we want to keep sample less, I mean if the group has more than 100 samples i want to take sample size of 100, if less - leave it as it is). I couldn't find one example of achieving something similar, and any ideas are appretiated.
For now the only idea I have is to forget about groupby, create lets say list of groups or something like

```
groups_list=[]

for i in df.some_id.unique():


    groups_list.append(df[df_some_id==i].apply(weird_sampling))

def weird_sampling(df):

    if (df.shape[0]>99):
        return df.sample(100)
    return df
```

But it seems extremely unefficient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the cleanest answer might be to shuffle your data and then select up to `n` of each group:

```py
# maximum number of elements in group
n = 100

# sample(frac=1) --> randomise the order
# groupby("some_id").head(n) --> select up to n
df.sample(frac=1).groupby("some_id").head(n)
```

Comment: indeed, clean solution which works, thanks for an answer, I was thinking about the order of sample and groupby here (it might be better/faster reversed) but it probably doesnt matter too much

Answer (score 2):

After some more trials with this problem I came up with this idea, which still may not be the best or most efficient solution, but is already much better and does the job

```
 df = df.groupby("some_id").apply(lambda x:  x.sample(n = 100) if (x.shape[0]>99) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

very similar to above answer by Igor but I guess less hardcoded and using `random_state` and `reset_index`. I would advise to use `random_state` if you want to make your results reproducible.

```
def sample(df, sample_size, seed):
    return df.sample(n=min(len(df), sample_size), random_state=seed)

df_sample = df.groupby(['some_id']).apply(sample, sample_size=100, seed=67871215).reset_index(drop=True)
df_sample
```